# Programmatically Changes Default Printer Orientation in 64bits program？

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm working on an old program. The program needs to generate a complex html page, and then print it. And depends on the html page, sometimes, it needs to print the html using different orientations.

The way it works now is: once it generated the html page, it uses a dll provided by Microsoft to programmatically change the default print orientation, then print. The dll (pageset.dll) is from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/198901 .

The pageset.dll is a 32bit dll, so the program uses this dll has to be built for X86 or AnyCPU. Now, we need to add some features, which need to use a SDK to drive a camera. The SDK has to be 64bits on 64bits windows. Now, here comes the problem. If build as X64 on 64bits windows, then the pageset.dll won't work anymore. But if build as X86 or AnyCPU, then the SDK won't work.

So, the question is:

is there a way to programmatically change default Printer Orientation in 64bits program？ any suggestions?

It is a C# .net program.